# How to add multiple PGP keys to my keybase ID?

Tags: pgp, private-key

I am using [keybase](http://keybase.io) and I try to add to add a secondary PGP key to my ID. However, when I try to select a key from my local keyring, I get the following message.

```
 ~ $ keybase pgp select
▶ ERROR You already have a PGP key registered (0CF0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 3200)
Specify the `--multi` flag to override this check
```

From this [blog post](https://keybase.io/blog/keybase-new-key-model) I understand it is totally possible to add multiple keys and accounts to your keybase ID. But how? The error message above tells me something about a `--multi` flag, but it seems my keybase version does not recognize it:

```
 ~ $ keybase pgp --multi select
Incorrect Usage.
[...]
Error parsing command line arguments: flag provided but not defined: -multi
```

Or:

```
 ~ $ keybase --multi pgp select
Incorrect Usage.
[...]
Error parsing command line arguments: flag provided but not defined: -multi
```

How to add multiple PGP keys to my keybase ID?

Edit: Keybase version 1.0.17 on ArchLinux.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's `keybase pgp select --multi` – that is, an option to the `select` subcommand.

Comment: how can this be done from the keybase.io WUI?